# Angular $Scope Deconstructing Patterns Error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to hardcode some data into my angular $scope like with this controller file:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.public')
    .controller('PublicController', Controller);

  /** @ngInject */
  function Controller($scope, $log, app_media) {
    $scope.tags = [{
      name = 'clock'
    }, {
      name = 'eye'
    }, {
      name = "ball"
    }];
  }
})();
```

when i go to use it in my views it looks like this:

```
<md-grid-list md-gutter="1em" md-row-height="20px" md-cols="3">
  <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="tag in tags" class="repeated-item">
    {{tag.name}}
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

but alas I'm getting this error in the chrome console: `"Shorthand property assignments are valid only in destructuring patterns"`

what does this mean and how can I fix? I've looked into destructuring patterns and it looks like it's the syntax for being able to assign object literals to variables? thanks! :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do ? Maybe put in the equivalent ES5 code that you want to achieve ? Otherwise looking your code, your `tag` list is not correct. The `name` property should be assigned using a `:`, and not a `=`:  `{name: 'clock'}`

Comment: Your object literal syntax is incorrect. It should be `{ name: 'clock' }`, etc

Comment: nice thanks guys fixed with the ':' and not the '=' post an answer and I'll give you credit :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `tags` list is not correct. Properties should be assigned using a `:` like so:

```
$scope.tags = [
  { name: 'clock' },
  { name: 'eye' },
  { name: "ball" }
];
```